# Export char*[] to C#

Tags: c#, c++

I have a structure in C++ that contains char*[]

```
struct Adapters {
    int iAdapterIndex[6];
    int iBusNumber[6];
    int iDeviceNumber[6];
    char *iAdapterName[6];
    char *iDisplayName[6];
};

extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) int GET_ADAPTERS_INFO(Adapters* send)
        {    
                .........       

                for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
                {
                    if (lpAdapterInfo[i].iBusNumber > -1)
                    {
                        send->iAdapterIndex[i] = lpAdapterInfo[i].iAdapterIndex;
                        send->iBusNumber[i] = lpAdapterInfo[i].iBusNumber;
                        send->iDeviceNumber[i] = lpAdapterInfo[i].iDeviceNumber;
                        send->iAdapterName[i] = lpAdapterInfo[i].strAdapterName;
                        send->iDisplayName[i] = lpAdapterInfo[i].strDisplayName;
                    }
                }        
            return 0;
        }
}
```

I call a function that passes this structure to C#

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Adapters
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 6)]
    public int[] iAdapterIndex;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 6)]
    public int[] iBusNumber;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 6)]
    public int[] iDeviceNumber;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 6)]
    public char[] iAdapterName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 6)]
    public char[] iDisplayName;
};

[DllImport("Example.dll", EntryPoint = "GET_ADAPTERS_INFO", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern int GET_ADAPTERS_INFO(out Adapters adapters);
```

But in the end I get garbage in arrays with char*. I have tried different UnmanagedType but no success. What to do?

UPD 1 :

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Adapters
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 6)]
    public int[] iAdapterIndex;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 6)]
    public int[] iBusNumber;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 6)]
    public int[] iDeviceNumber;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPTStr, SizeConst = 6)]
    public string[] iAdapterName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPTStr, SizeConst = 6)]
    public string[] iDisplayName;
};
```

it will cause the application to crash

Answer (score 5):

Your C struct contains arrays of char ***pointers***. An array of char pointers is not an array of chars.

However, your C# struct declares char arrays.

So, the "garbage" you are seeing in your C# struct char arrays are actually the bytes that make up the pointer values in the C struct char pointer arrays being interpreted as char values by the marshaller.

I am not entirely certain about what you are supposed to do. However, note the following: In C, which is lacking a native string type, char pointers are typically used to handle strings. You can think of an array of char pointers as an array of strings. (*iAdapterName* and *iDisplayName* can be thought of as an array of six strings.)

Therefore, i tend to suggest your C# struct should define string arrays and not char arrays. (Not sure if you would need to explicitly specify *UnmanagedType.LPTStr* or alike for the [`ArraySubType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute.arraysubtype) field of the *MarshalAs* attribute, though.)

Comment: Unfortunately the type of variable string will cause the application to crash, and if I specify ArraySubType, it will not affect the garbage

Comment: (1/2) That points at something being up with those pointers in the char pointer arrays. You will have to use the debugger (both the unmanaged C debugger as well as the C# debugger) then to troubleshoot your program. First check in the C debugger if GET_ADAPTERS_INFO correctly populates the whole struct. Also check if the char pointers are referring to properly NULL-terminated string. Make sure that those strings are not allocated on the stack (if they do, they would not survive the GET_ADAPTERS_INFO method returning, leaving your struct with dangling invalid pointers).

Comment: (2/2) Then, for troubleshooting purposes, in the C# struct turn your string arrays into pointer arrays `IntPtr[]`. Check then, if the pointer values  in the IntPtr array are the same as you saw in the C debugger and whether you can successfully dereference these pointers without crashing. If the pointer values appear correct but you cannot dereference them, you know whatever these pointers pointed at did not survive outside the GET_ADAPTERS_INFO function. Good luck hunting!